# Script for automated torrent downloads (from announce urls in IRC)

Tags: linux, automation, irc, bittorrent

Some time ago I read a discussion in [/r/linux](http://www.reddit.com/r/linux) and someone mentioned a script that checks new messages in IRC channel (in irssi client) and if they contain announce urls for torrents, they are passed to a torrent client (rtorrent) for downloading. Sadly, I didn't bookmark it, nor I could find it now. Maybe someone has a similar script?

All suggestions for making one are appreciated.

Comment: Actually, its not that hard to code, I suggest you code your own, it feels better.

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to do that, it sounds very prone to abuse. Anyway, I think that this is more suitable for superuser.com, although I'm note sure if you get a better answer there.

Comment: i agree with ruel. - it would be very easy to setup a pre-existing irc logging bot that logs to a file, grep the file for url's and use wget to download them into a watch directory for a torrent client. job done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an [irssi plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/autodl-irssi/) for this.

> Plugin for Irssi which monitors torrent IRC announce channels, downloads torrent files based on a user-defined filter, and then sends the torrent files to a local or remote torrent client. Supports several different private trackers.

---

If you're looking for a script, there's [this Perl script](http://rusak.pastebin.com/djF2nNGJ)